# If $A:=[0,1]$, $B:=(-1,2)$, $f:A\mapsto B$ is continuous, and $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Is $f(A)\subset A$ true or false?

Tags: functions

If $A:=[0,1]$ and $B:=(-1,2)$, the function $f:A\mapsto B$ is continuous and $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Is $f(A)\subset A$ true or false?

So I think this is true. Because we know that both $y$ of function are part of $A$ and the $x$ is part of $A$, is my thinking good and how do I prove this?

Comment: No, it's not true. Try to draw a continuous graph of a function $f$ in the  $[0,1]\times (-1,2)$ with anchored points at $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: How it's not true, can you explain me better?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. For instance, $f(x)=(1+2x)(1-x)$ is continuous and satisfies $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$, but
$$f([0,\frac{1}{2}]) = [1,\frac{9}{8}].$$
In fact, note that $f(\frac14) = \frac98\not\in A$.
Therefore,
$$f([0,1]) = [0,\frac{9}{8}] \not\subset[0,1].$$

The following graph shows it more clearly:
[image: Plot]

---

EDIT:

Imagine that you have an elastic band. Fix one end in the point $P=(x=0,f(x)=1)$ and the other one in $Q=(x=1,f(x)=0)$. If the band is tight enough, it will form a straight line form $P$ to $Q$. But if you pick it in the middle and start stretching it upwards, at some point it will surpass the top limit $f(x)=1$.

Mathematically speaking, you need to build a function taht behaves similarly: for instance, a parabola. You start from $f(x)=a(x-b)(x-c)$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, where $b$ and $c$ will be the zeros of $f$. Since $f(1)=0$, you can simply take $c=1$. You also need that $f(x)>1$ for some intermediate $x\in(0,1)$, so the second zero has to be on the left of $x=0$. Take, for instance, $b=-\frac12$. The remaining constant $a$ can be obtained by imposing $1=f(0)=-\frac{a}{2}$.

---

EDIT2:
Note that is not the same $f([0,1])$ and $[f(0),f(1)]$. The first denotes the image of the interval $[0,1]$, that is,
$$f([0,1])=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ y=f(x) \text{ for }x\in[0,1]\}$$
The latter is simply an interval limited by two values, which in fact are badly ordered since $f(0)>f(1)$. It would correspond to the interval $[0,1]$.

[image: Plot2]

Comment: Why you use 1/2?

Comment: f(0)=(2+0)(1-0)=2 It doesn't satisfie that f(0)=1

Comment: Sorry, it is $f(x)=(1+2x)(1-x)$. $[0,\frac12]$ is the part of $A$ whose image by $f$ stays out of $A$.

Comment: Can you explain me how do I know how will function go?

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: So I could take two funncitons for example y1=2x+1 x=0 x=1 and than y=1 y=3
and the second 3x-3 for x=1 and 0 y=0 and y=-3

Comment: Well, as far as I understood, you need a unique function, don't you? Then, why two functions?

Comment: Hey this is not good (1+2*1/2)(1-1/2)=1 not 9/8

Comment: @AkaliGreen I know. It is $f(\frac14)=\frac98$. You need to take into account that $[0,\frac98]=f([0,1])\ne [f(0),f(1)]=[0,1]$. See my new edit above.

Answer (score 0):

need not be true 
 for consider the function which is the lines joining (0,1) to (1/2,3/2) and the line joining (1/2,3/2) to (1,0)

Comment: draw a graph using the above data given by me then find what is the range of the function you just drawn over....